# Searching an array and deleting its value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a column in my mysql table that stores data like so,

```
'fb:username;yt:youtubeUsername;tw:twitterUsername;uk:websiteURL'
```

All values are seperated by ';'. What I want to know is how I would remove a value of this array (say the user wanted to remove their YouTube account link), how I would search the field using the explode function and cleanly remove the value from the row.

Hope I've not confused you.

```
        $social = explode(";", $arrayquery['socialNetworks']);
        $count = substr_count($arrayquery['socialNetworks'], ';') + 1;

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
            # Seperate data so we can read it
            $prefix = substr($social[$i], 0, 2);
            $url = strstr($social[$i], ':');
            $url = substr($url, 1); # Remove : from resources

 { my script I need to run in For loop. }
        }
```

This is the script I use to extract my data from the field.

Comment: and this is why you normalize DB tables, so you're not stuck using hideous logic like this. A properly normalized table would reduce this down to a **SIMPLE** `DELETE FROM ...` query

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the power of database at all.

The easiest would be to have for example a table like this :

```
id    facebook    youtube            twitter            uk
1     username    youtubeUsername    twitterUsername    http://stackoverflow.com
```

Now it is a simple task to update only one column at a time, example : `UPDATE table SET youtube = "" WHERE id = 1;`

Easy but you need to update the table schema if you need more "kind" of information. You can make this more flexible :

Table 1

```
id    `othercolumrelatedtouser`
1     'otherdata'
```

Table 2

```
id    table1ID    tag         value
1     1           facebook    username
2     1           youtube     youtubeUsername
3     1           twitter     twitterUsername
4     1           url         http://stackoverflow.com
```

Now you will be able to use something like `DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE table1ID = 1 AND tag = "youtube";`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "remove"? Does it mean you want to remove a specific network from the string, or do you want to remove just value of a network while the network will still exist in the string. Anyways, here is solution to both of these problems:

```
$arrayquery['socialNetworks'] = 'fb:username;yt:youtubeUsername;tw:twitterUsername;uk:websiteURL';
$networks   = explode_networks( $arrayquery['socialNetworks'] );

//Uncomment this print_r to see what $networks looks like
//print_r( $networks );

//here you have the choice:
//To set the value of Twitter account (for example) to an empty string  

$networks['tw'] = '';

//or if you want to remove twitter from the list of networks, remove the above line and uncomment the below one
//unset( $networks['tw'] );

$networks   = implode_networks( $networks );

//See how your string looks like
//echo $networks    



//Functions

function explode_networks( $networks ) {
    $networks = array_filter( explode( ';' , $networks ) );
    $return = array( );
    foreach( $networks as $netw ) {
        list( $nw , $data ) = explode( ':' , $netw );
        $return[$nw] = $data;
    }
    return $return;
}

function implode_networks( $networks ) {
    $return = array( );
    foreach( $networks as $nw => $data ) {
        $return[] = $nw . ':' . $data;
    }
    return implode( ';' , $return );
}
```

Hope it helps.